# How to replace same pattern text with empty space using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am having problem with regex which I wanted to select and replace the .pipe() until the semicolon part. For each block of functions. I have tried this pattern but no go.

```
.pipe\([\w\W]+\);
```

Any suggestion on how actually the right regex pattern for this problem? Thanks

```
  getBanks(): Observable<Bank[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.API + '/banks').pipe(
      map((res: Response) => <Bank[]>res.json()));
  }

  getBankByCode(code: string): Observable<Bank> {
    return this.http.get<Bank>(this.API + '/banks/' + code).pipe(
      map((res: Response) => <Bank>res.json()));
  }
```

Comment: Where's your code? Your "code snippet" seems to be your input string (?).

Comment: Sorry my mistake. Edited my question to use code block. 
It's the input that I want to replace.

Comment: Have you set the multiline flag in your REGEX?

Comment: @StevenSpungin If you mean the `m` flag, that only affects `^` and `$`, which are not used here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your '+' lazy using '?'

```js
let rx = /\.pipe\([\w\W]+?\);/g

const input = `getBanks(): Observable<Bank[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.API + '/banks').pipe(
      map((res: Response) => <Bank[]>res.json()));
  }

  getBankByCode(code: string): Observable<Bank> {
    return this.http.get<Bank>(this.API + '/banks/' + code).pipe(
      map((res: Response) => <Bank>res.json()));
  }
`

let res = rx.exec(input)
while (res) {
  console.log(res)
  res = rx.exec(input)

}
```